# Script to delete a user account from G Suite Admin SDK

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am writing a script that fetches a data from a spread sheet and based on every entry entered in the spread sheet, it fetches the data which is basically email addresses and deletes a user's account from the domain.

```
//** Delete the users on submitting the "Submit" button

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //Logger.log(e);
  //Run this function passing on event "e" when the form is submitted.
  //Object e has form parameters sourced from the sheet attached to the form
  deleteUsers(e);
}

//Logs all the info from the spreadsheet and deletes the user
function deleteUsers() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('managerEmail: ' + data[i][0]);
    Logger.log('email: ' + data[i][1]);
    Logger.log('trasferToEmail: ' + data[i][3]);

    var managerEmail = data[i][0];
    var email = data[i][1];
    var trasferToEmail = data[i][3];

    var request = {
   'url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/' + email,
   'method' : 'DELETE'
    };
  }
```

But I am still unsuccessful in deleting an account. I actually tried to implement it based on this doc https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/delete but didn't know how to use it. Any ideas? Sorry if this is a stupid question! I am a novice in  Google scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending `e` to `deleteUsers()`, but that function doesn't receive any parameters. No need to access the spreadsheet data when it's already provided by the `onFormSubmit()`–look at the [event object documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) for reference.

```
function deleteUser(e) { 
  var data = e.namedValues;
  var managerEmail = data["Manager Email"][0]; //You'll need to adjust the field names to match with your form data
  var email = data["Email"][0];
  var transferToEmail = data["Transfer to Email"][0];
  var response = AdminDirectory.Users.remove(email);
}
```

To make sure that your trigger is correctly set up, first have the form responses get saved to your spreadsheet. Then Edit > Current project's triggers and copy these settings:
[image]

To make `AdminDirectory` work, you need to [enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). (In the script editor, go to Resources > Advanced Google services and switch "on" Admin Directory API. Then click the link at the bottom of the modal to enable the Admin SDK in the API Console.)
[image]

If I was mistaken about what data the form is collecting and you really do need to pull the data from spreadsheet (assuming the form isn't connected to the sheet), then you need to [create a trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) for when there is a submission to that form. Run this function to install the trigger.

```
function installFormTrigger() {
  var form = FormApp.openById("FORM_ID");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("deleteUsers")
  .forForm(form)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}
```

Then your original `deleteUsers()` function will work almost as you had it, but with the addition of `AdminDirectory`.

```
function deleteUsers() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SheetName"); //HIGHLY recommend using this instead
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var managerEmail = data[i][0];
    var email = data[i][1];
    var trasferToEmail = data[i][3];
    var response = AdminDirectory.Users.remove(email);
  }
}
```

Note that in your for loop, you might come across an invalid email or `AdminDirectory` could through an error, so I'd suggest implementing [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) and [logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer @Diego, the spreadsheet actually contains the response obtained from the form and with which the spreadsheet is connected. Also, If I want to simply suspend the account is there a way? I tried with `AdminDirectory.Users.update({'suspended':true}, email)` but that is not helping.

Comment: I am actually trying to delete a user account when a user submits the google form (for off-boarding) with the email id, it has to simply suspend or delete the account.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but looking at the sample code for [aliases](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#create_alias), try `{suspended: true}` or `{suspended: 'true'}`. In the alias example, I see that they aren't surrounding property names in quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but even though I have the data in the spreadsheet https://ibb.co/kUGXcH, its showing `Resource Not Found: userKey` for the code `var response = AdminDirectory.Users.update({suspended:'true'},email);` https://ibb.co/fAcxcH, also I have created a dummy account with the email id in G Suite, but its still showing the error, any help?

Comment: Try [getting the user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#get_user) first, and then looking for their user key in the returned object.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use `AdminDirectory.Users.remove(email);` rather than making a request to the API like you are doing.

Keep it in a variable if you want to log the response `var request = AdminDirectory.Users.remove(data[i][1]);`

To activate the AdminDirectory;

1. Go to Resources -> Advanced Google services 
   [image]
2. Enable the Admin Directory and then click on the link to the Google API console.
   [image]
3. Click Enable APIs and Services
   [image]
4. Search for Admin SDK
   [image]
5. Click on Admin SDK and then click 'Enable'

Comment: When I tried it in the code its showing `ReferenceError: "AdminDirectory" is not defined.` error. Is'nt `AdminDirectory` an inbuilt class?

Comment: If you intend on distributing this form to members of your domain to allow them to use it to delete users, I would advise against it or at least I wouldn't do it onFormSubmit.

Comment: Thanks @james-donnellan for the answer, If I want to simply suspend the account is there a way? I tried with `AdminDirectory.Users.update({'suspended':true}, email)` but that is not helping.

Comment: I am actually trying to delete a user account when a user submits the google form (for off-boarding) with the email id, it has to simply suspend or delete the account.

Comment: `AdminDirectory.Users.update({'suspended':true}, email)` works fine for me, try logging and looking at the response. `Logger.log(AdminDirectory.Users.update({'suspended':true}, email)`

Comment: Thanks, but even though I have the data in the spreadsheet https://ibb.co/kUGXcH, its showing `Resource Not Found: userKey` for the code `var response = AdminDirectory.Users.update({suspended:'true'},email);` https://ibb.co/fAcxcH, also I have created a dummy account with the email id in G Suite, but its still showing the error, any help?

Comment: Just to confirm: response = AdminDirectory.Users.update({'suspended':true},'12345@example.com'); note the position of the quotes. Also check that you are skipping the header row. It would be best to edit your OP with the current code and question.

Comment: Thanks @James this helped